# Routing Client to an IP in ASP

Tags: asp.net, ip

I need to extract Client IP address and his location. Based on his location I need to route client to specific IP adddress. I succeeded in getting client IP address and his location. Can anyone suggest me a way to route Client to specified IP. 
      Also let me know a reliable web service which gives me accurate location based on IP address given.
Thanking You.

Comment: What you are asking for is something that should be handled at the DNS level, or possibly at the reverse proxy level, not in your application.  Routing someone to a different IP address means you are basically going to see the ip address in the url bar, rather than your domain name.  What you're trying to do is called geographic targeting.  This is not something that someone with little knowledge of how the internet works should be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easy

```
<script>
window.location="http://example.com/your/new/uri"
</script>
```